# Remove object inside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with ajax call when deleting an object from an array and updating the list view.

Inside a loop, If I can confirm the deletion of the object online I want to delete that same object from the native array. The problem is that the deletion from the native array does not work and I dunno why.

The code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tempShoppingCartArray.length; i++) {
                var row = tempShoppingCartArray[i];

      if(chosenSubMenuID.sid == row.sid && row.sent == 0){

           var myUrl = someURL

           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: myUrl,
                crossDomain: true,

                beforeSend: function(xhr) {

                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", wsTOKEN);
                },

                success: function(response) {

                      tempShoppingCartArray.slice(i,1); //this code does not work
                      $("#shopping-list li").eq(i).remove(); //this code does not work

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

                }
           });
       }
  }
```

Comment: When your `success` method is called all the `i`'s will be equal to `tempShoppingCartArray.length`.

Comment: hmmm that may be the case, so how do I get the correct index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is because although you think that in the `success` method of your ajax request that `i` will be equal to the current iteration from the `for` loop, it will in fact have the final value for all requests.

Take this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLhgL74m/):

```
var array = ["a","b","c"];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url: '/echo/json',
        success: function(){
            console.log(i,"success");
        }
    });
};
```

You may expect that the output in the console would be

> 0 success
>   1 success
>   2 success

When in actual fact it is

> 3 success
>   3 success
>   3 success

This is due to the asynchronous nature of the ajax call, having made the call control returns immediately and therefore executes all of the 3 requests straight after one another. When the first `success` is called, the loop control variable has already reached its limit (3 in this case).

The way to fix this is to produce a scope around the ajax call using an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), and pass the loop control variable in as a parameter, this gives the [expected result](http://jsfiddle.net/hLhgL74m/1/):

```
var array = ["a","b","c"];    
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){

    (function(x){
        $.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url: '/echo/json',
            success: function(){
                console.log(x,"success");
            }
        });
    })(i)
};
```

> 0 success
>   1 success
>   2 success

Comment: Brilliant, it was exactly what I was thinking but didn't knew how to do it. Thanks :) (will up-vote other answers for the effort)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the splice function, not slice:

```
tempShoppingCartArray.splice(i,1);
```

The slice function is not actually altering the tempShoppingCartArray variable, but rather, calling array.slice(a,b) returns a new array containing the elements in array from index a to index b. With array.splice(a,b), array has b elements after and including the element at index a removed from it.

Also as @Jamiec pointed out, since ajax does asynchronous calls, your i will continue incrementing whilst the request is processing. By the time this finishes i will have reached the length of the array. Try throw a break in after your ajax call.

```
$ajax(....);
break;
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Tried it with splice and still nothing.

Comment: The break wont do a thing different. See my answer.

Comment: @Jamiec Can you explain why please? If you exit the loop when i is at the value you want to delete (Note I did I assume he wants to delete only one item) would i not live on with the value it stops on? Does i disappear for some reason?

Comment: Ah, I missed the `if` bit of his code - so yes it looks like he's searching through looking for only *one* item to delete. If thats the case then your `break` solution does have merit. Sorry I missed that.